# registerForContextMenu not working as well

Tags: android, listview

I create a context menu for custom listview

```
orderProducts =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listProductInDoc);
    orderProducts.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    ArrayList<ResultOfProductInDoc> resultOfProductInDoc = GetResultOfProductInDoc();
    orderProducts.setAdapter(new CustomListOfProductInDoc(resultOfProductInDoc,OrderActivity.this));

    View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_order, null, false);orderProducts.addFooterView(footerView);
    registerForContextMenu(orderProducts);
```

but menu is showing only for footer,when i remove footer he also not working, can somebody help me what is my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved, problem was in xml layout.